# Unable to generate pdf in production server usng wicked pdf gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked pdf to generate pdf. Its working fine in local server but on production mode i got into below errors:

> Failed to execute: ["/usr/local/bundle/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q",
>   "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20190902-26-811syo.html",
>   "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20190902-26-1x3596l.pdf"] Error: PDF
>   could not be generated! Command Error:

I am running my application on an **Alpine container**.

Comment: It says command error, can you log-in/ssh to the machine/container with the same user as the process which executes this command and checks if you're able to run the command there?

Comment: post full backtrace errors and code that invokes this in your question.

Comment: Have you installed `wkhtmltopdf` on this server? `wicked_pdf` requires `wkhtmltopdf` to be installed.